# DNS redirect based in IP

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

I'm looking for some help.
We got a WAN, which includes several different locations across US and Europe. Now I have a need that when someone SSH to a DNS, he will get connected to a server close to his location.

When I was looking around for info, all I could find is DNS redirect based on Geo location.

But I would need it for internal IPs, so no Geo location information available.

And looking at the DNS record types, I don't think I can set it up with just another DNS record.

Comment: What kind of DNS are you using internally? You should be able to define DNS resolution to local resources internally.

Comment: Using PowerDNS.

Answer (score 1):

You can do GeoDNS for Internal networks using Perl Standford::DNSServer. Check out [this article](http://jpmens.net/2007/04/02/location-based-geo-dns-in-a-private-network/). You can just delegate that zone to this from PowerDNS.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with bind and views,  set an acl for each ip range,  then configure a zone for each view.

This is the same a geodns, but you are feeding it a custom range.

For powerdns, use the GeoIP dns with a custom range per their [doc](https://doc.powerdns.com/md/authoritative/backend-geoip/)

Comment: We are using PowerDNS at the moment. Any idea if I can achieve the same with it?

Comment: Powerdns's opinion is views are unnecessary,you can do geodns with this guide https://doc.powerdns.com/md/authoritative/backend-geoip/

Answer (score 0):

If you have the resources available, I would suggest Anycast. It uses "loopholes" in routing protocols to the nearest (network-wise) server.

`[Client A] --- (rtr 1) ----------- (rtr 2) --- [Client B]
                  |                   |
              [server 1]          [server 2]`

It works by server 1 & server 2 listening on the same address and rtr 1 and rtr 2 both advertising that ip address/route.

Comment: Any cast is a little overkill for this